# mysql select column in table where two other columns are equal in the referenced tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got four tables A, B, C, and D.

```
Table A: value1, city
Table B: value2, city
Table C: value3, city
Table D: value1, value2, value3
```

I need to select value2 (I'm guessing from Table D) where value1 and value3 are in the same row in Table D and both have the same "city" in their rows on tables A and C.

So, if Table A has a rows

```
13, Chicago
14, Milwaukee
15, St. Louis
```

and Table C has rows

```
78, Chicago
89, St. Paul
94, St. Louis
```

and Table D has rows

```
13, One, 89
13, Two, 78
14, Three, 78
15, Four, 94
```

Then I need to print out:

```
Two
Four
```

Comment: The operation you're looking for is a "JOIN".

Comment: [*fiddle demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6471d/2)

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid thanks for turning me on to that site.  Going to be a very nice resource for the rest of this semester.  And your answer was also absolutely correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select
  value2
from
  tablea a
  inner join tablec c on a.value1= c.value1
  inner join tableb b on c.value3= b.value3
where
  b.city = a.city
```

Comment: @BWONG Thanks! I didnt realize that was the issue or i'd have thrown more votes your way.  There's a few to keep you going.  Good luck!

Comment: I'm paying back today!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TableD.value2 
FROM TableD 
JOIN TableC ON TableC.value3=TableD.value3 
JOIN TableA ON TableA.value1=TableD.value1 AND TableA.city = TableC.city
```